# cv2 not work after install mediapipe library

Tags: python, opencv, pip, mediapipe

I want to make handtracker program using python but the tutorial tell me to install mediapipe library, then I installed it. Before that it's okay using cv2 to stream my camera, but after installing mediapipe, the cv2 doesn't work
here the message :

````
>>>import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 175, in bootstrap
    if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
    py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\gapi\__init__.py", line 290, in <module>
    cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import) ```
````

I tried to install opencv again but always get this message :

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\windows\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.21.1)
```

but the problem still there. How do I fix it?

Edited : this is my pip list

```
C:\Users\windows>pip list
Package               Version
--------------------- --------
absl-py               1.1.0
attrs                 21.4.0
cycler                0.11.0
fonttools             4.33.3
kiwisolver            1.4.2
matplotlib            3.5.2
mediapipe             0.8.10
numpy                 1.21.1
opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66
opencv-python         4.5.3.56
packaging             21.3
Pillow                8.3.1
pip                   22.1.2
protobuf              4.21.1
pygame                2.1.2
pyparsing             3.0.9
python-dateutil       2.8.2
pyzbar                0.1.8
setuptools            56.0.0
six                   1.16.0
```

Comment: Ensure you have only one version of OpenCV installed in your system/environment

Comment: perhaps mediapipe installed a **conflicting** package of OpenCV and now you've got multiple? probably. please list all the installed packages using pip. use `pip list` and find everything relating to `opencv` in that list. [edit] your question and add the information. if you see multiple opencv packages, uninstall all of them (using pip), then try reinstalling mediapipe.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz There is opencv-contrib-python and opencv-python in there, I'll try it

Comment: I found the problem, when I installed mediapipe there is opencv-contrib-python, make the opencv-python twice

Comment: I found a dirty fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72897683/13147413

Answer (score 5):

I have the same situation like above
you can try it:

```
pip install "opencv-python-headless<4.3"
```

This command has successfully resolved this situation

Reference:https://github.com/Rudrabha/Wav2Lip/issues/387

Answer (score 1):

In any version(ex: 4.6.0.66), when you install any 2 of 3 packages: opencv-contrib-python, opencv-python-headless, opencv-python, make sure they have the same version. I also got the same error, I found out their versions are different. Then a synchronous update solved the problem.

Comment: installing those concurrently is a bad idea. only install one of them. they all contain the base modules (minus highgui, if headless).

Comment: yeah, you do not understand what I mean. I mean with one or two of those libraries (you can install according to your needs). But make sure they are the same version. As question problem above, he/she didn't install opencv-contrib-python, opencv-python same version so gave error, don't know if there is another error but I also had this problem and solved it's like that.

Comment: I do understand and am puzzled why you mistake that. it's still a bad idea to install those concurrently. that frequently leads to issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and I only have `opencv-python` installed. The problem is solved by installing `opencv-python-headless`.

---

My problem is more complicate than that. Actually the opencv-python is already installed in "root", but when I login as another user (dev), I get the problem as OP.
I can install `opencv-python-headless` or `opencv-contrib-python` manually, then the system will work. But if I install them in "root", I sill have the same problem.

So the final solution I use is to reinstall `opencv-python` in my user environment (dev):

`pip3 install  --upgrade --force-reinstall opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

I fix such a problem  using the following commands.

pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python

Answer (score 0):

the following solution

pip install "opencv-python-headless<4.3"

fixed the error below when building OpenCV from source!

> > > import cv2
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2_*init*_.py", line 181, in 
> > > bootstrap()
> > > File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2_*init*_.py", line 153, in bootstrap
> > > native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
> > > File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in import_module
> > > return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> > > ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Is that not just a copy of an existing answer? Or a comment to  it? In both case, please avoid answering old question without making sure you have a new solution that was not given at the time