# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, opencv

This happened out of the blue, I was able to import cv2 but now I get 'AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)' error when I import it. The things I tried:

1-uninstalling and installing opencv.
2-In cmd, I typed "pip list" and opencv-python package is listed. I ran "python" command and tried importing cv2 but I get the same error. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634520/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-cascadeclas)

Comment: I've already tried that solution does not work.

Comment: and how's this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545779/cv2-not-work-after-install-mediapipe-library

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAydın Create a new virtual environment, install OpenCV and try

Comment: I changed my anaconda environment but it caused some other bugs. I just uninstall anaconda and installed it. It works now

Comment: I found a dirty fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72897683/13147413

Answer (score 77):

I also had the same problem with opencv-python-4.6.0.66

I solved this error by just downgrading opencv. you can follow this command.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: for me (in a container) `pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.64` worked. The newest version, albeit also headless, did not work, it showed a different error.

Comment: If your issue is indeed that the currently installed package is out of date, `pip install opencv-python --upgrade` will get you the latest one.

Comment: it worked for me and the git-sym package! thank you

Comment: what if i need `opencv-python>=4.6`?

Answer (score 41):

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

and then

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.62
```

Comment: thanks sir! this helped me out today with a scary issue

Answer (score 7):

Same problem here when I had:

```
> pip list
opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66
opencv-python         4.5.4.58
```

Upgraded opencv-python to 4.6.0.66 (`> pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66`) and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. Just in case, to get the list `pip list | grep opencv`

Answer (score 2):

Updating the package https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ to version 4.6.0.66 worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. I tried some of the solutions. Also, I had "**ImportError: cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (C:\Users\user_name\anaconda3\envs\tf_od\lib\site-packages\cv2\cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd)**" this error.

And **I resolve the issue** by checking OpenCV libraries installed on my Anaconda Environment by

`pip list`

```
opencv-contrib-python         4.6.0.66
opencv-python                 4.6.0.66
opencv-python-headless        4.5.2.52
```

I think everyone may have a different combination of these versions and others. So you should check and uninstall all OpenCV libs. And then install opencv-python.

**In my case:**

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless

pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading opencv solved the issue for me: !pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have earned 15 reputation points you will be able to [vote other users' posts up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32452557)

Answer (score 1):

As of February 2023, had the same error with opencv-python version 3.4.4.19. Upgrading to version 3.4.5.20 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my anaconda environment but it caused some other bugs. I just uninstall anaconda and installed it. It works now