# Docker container build failed but works on local machine

Tags: python, docker, containers, fastapi, opencv

I'm trying to build python fastapi to docker but it failed to run the container

> 2023-01-03 10:45:30 Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in 
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     sys.exit(main())
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in **call**
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 404, in main
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     run(
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 569, in run
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     server.run()
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return future.result()
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     config.load()
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 477, in load
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "", line 883, in exec_module
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/./app/main.py", line 1, in 
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     import cv2
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 181, in 
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     bootstrap()
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 175, in bootstrap
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/gapi/**init**.py", line 290, in 
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30     cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline
> 2023-01-03 10:45:30 AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)

commands to build container
docker-compose up -d

docker file

```
FROM python:3.10.8
RUN pip3 install fastapi uvicorn
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -U pip wheel cmake
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
CMD ["uvicorn","app.main:app","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

docker-compose yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
    core_api:
      build: .
      container_name: "kycengine"
      ports:
          - "8000:8000"
      volumes:
          - ./app/:/app
```

the build success but when try to run it fails

Python Code

```
import cv2
import os
import face_recognition
import easyocr
import time
import fastapi
import pydantic
import deepface

class Data(pydantic.BaseModel):
    FileName: str
    
class FaceExtractor(pydantic.BaseModel):
    Data: str
    Name: str
    
class Matcher(pydantic.BaseModel):
    identity_image: str
    live_image: str

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"title": "KYC API"}

@app.post("/IDCardProcessor")
async def read_root(data: Data):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        IMAGE_PATH = data.FileName
        im_gray = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        reader = easyocr.Reader(['en','ar'], gpu=True)
        result = reader.readtext(im_gray,
                                batch_size = 1,
                                contrast_ths = .1,
                                decoder = 'greedy', 
                                detail = 1, paragraph=False, 
                                adjust_contrast = 0.9)

        print(str(result))
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
        return{str(result)}
    except:
        print(result)
        return{"An exception occurred"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706073/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-gapi-wip-gs

Comment: share the app/main.py file

Comment: A [mcve] would help. You're mounting a volume with unspecified content over a copy of some similarly named folder installed during image build. Don't do this, provide exact build steps and strip unnecessary parts. BTW: Catching an exception and writing a possibly unbound variable isn't useful. Write the exception instead!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues, but it isn't straightforward to help without the python code—some suggestions to start searching for the issue and suggestions.

1. `2023-01-03 10:45:30 cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline 2023-01-03 10:45:30 AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)`
   There seems to be an `import` issue in your code. Does the code work outside the container?
2. You copy in the `dockerfile` the content from the `app` folder to the container, and during container execution, you map the same folder into the container.
3. Move this line in your `dockerfile` `RUN pip3 install fastapi uvicorn` below that line `RUN pip install -U pip wheel cmake`. This can mess up versions and compatibility.

Comment: 1. Yes, It works
2. I didn't get this point
3. okay did that.