# Cannot import opencv because of circular import

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-lab

When trying to import opencv in jupyter lab notebook (`import cv2`) i get this error:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute
> 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular
> import)

I have tried installing opencv both via pip:

```
 pip install opencv-python
```

than via conda-forge:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

in different envs, also uninstalling and reinstalling.

If i try to import it via command line python i do not get any error.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions but I'm reluctant to close this as a duplicate because it smells like similar issues can be caused by multiple underlying problems. A small sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706073/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-gapi-wip-gs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634520/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-cascadeclas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545779/cv2-not-work-after-install-mediapipe-library. If any of these help we can use that as a duplicate target.

Comment: Hi, i'm aware of the other similar questions and also there's a github issue open, but no luck with te proposed solutions  and that's why i asked.

Comment: It would help if you could add to your question what you alteady tried to no avail.

Comment: I think this is a jupyter problem. No issues on vscode using the exact same environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a *dirty fix*, for the ones that are in a rush.

The error is produced by the last line (290) of the file: `/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/gapi/__init__.py`:

```
cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline
```

That seems like some sort of naming adjustment. **I commented out the line and the import error is gone** and the library seems to work ok.